# Hypothesis significance better than Mean Average Precision?

Tags: statistical-significance, mean

Consider I have two search engines, one (B) with Mean Average Precision higher than the other (B). Now, can this metric be enough to say that the first search engine A is better than the second one B?

If not, how would other methods such as hypothesis significance tests would help me find out which one is better?

Answer (score 1):

No!

These are 2 common methods to find out better one,

1. [Two-sample t-test](http://www.statsdirect.com/help/parametric_methods/utt.htm)
2. [Two-sample Z-test](http://www.stat.ucla.edu/%7Ecochran/stat10/winter/lectures/lect21.html)

after test, you get either of 3 results........1)precision of group 1 is better, 2)precision of group 2 is better, 3)precision of both groups did not differ significantly.

Comment: can you discuss this more? what does two-sample mean?

Comment: two-sample are the samples of 2 groups which you want to compare.

Comment: why are those two better?